# ImportError: No module named dbus

Tags: python, python-2.7, dbus-python

I installed Python2.7.12, installed dbus-python-1.2.4, suggesting that the installation is successful, but still can not be used, why?

```
Processing dependencies for dbus-python==1.2.4
Finished processing dependencies for dbus-python==1.2.4
```

Use process：

```
root@SKYPHY:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  7 2017, 15:21:53) 
[GCC 4.8.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dbus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not use setup.py installation, but to use ./configure to compile

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is to upgrade setuptools, it may help when you deal with this kind of error.

Comment: I would like to ask which upgrade version of the appropriate, I now setuptools is 7.0